# How does surefire cleanly shutdown?

Tags: maven, testng, surefire

Well, it seems to not do that, anyway.  My libraries use non-daemon threadpools that normally I have to explicitly shutdown in order to shutdown the application, yet surefire does not seem to require this.  By what method is surefire shutting down the threadpools anyway?  Is it just sigterm-ing or sigkill-ing itself?  And is it possible to require a clean shutdown as part of a test suite, e.g. in testng?

Answer (score 0):

You could perform any necessary cleanup using a @AfterSuite method.

Apart from that there is no way surefire or TestNG could possibly know about your necessary application cleanup.

Comment: I seem to be hitting issues with this. For some errors, even with @AfterSuite(alwaysRun=true) set, my clean up method often fails to run for some reason.